# SVG shapes with feGaussianBlur stdDeviation not rendering correctly on google chrome

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, svg, mask

So I am using an SVG mask on an image to make a blurry edged ellipse and for a while it was looking right on all browsers but then randomly the blurry effect on the svg looked really wrong on chrome and microsoft edge and I cannot figure out why it is happening or resolve the issue. I'm using the feGaussianBlur stdDeviation tags to give it the blurry edges and they apparently are doing different things on each browser. (firefox is how it supposed to be looking like).
Someone please guide me in the right direction :)

Here is the code I'm using to make the masked image

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400px" height="350px" class="rotating">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="20" />
    </filter>
    <mask id="mask">
      <ellipse cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="35%" ry="35%" fill="white" filter="url(#filter)"></ellipse>
    </mask>
  </defs>
                
                <image class="homepage-header-image " xlink:href="http://legendbranding.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/cropped-ryan-plomp-0iPebSCgKoA-unsplash-3.jpg" mask="url(#mask)"></image>
                </svg>
            </div>



<script>
     .header-description.media-on-right img.homepage-header-image {
        float: right;
      }
</script>
```

[SVG in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhZA8.jpg)

[SVG in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcPg7.jpg)

Comment: SVG does not like un-dimensioned elements. What is the dimension you want for your image element? And do you want your source image's aspect ratio kept or not? Please post the CSS of the relevant classes - otherwise this code is incomplete.

Comment: there isn't really anymore css that is relevant. It is mostly hardcoded like that and worked the way it did. Can you show me what I may include to possibly fix this issue

Comment: Add explicit dimensions and a preserveAspectRatio to your image element. Try preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"

Comment: unfortunately, that didn't help. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I have come to terms that this method doesn't work with WebKit so I need a way to achieve this effect that will work for all browsers

Comment: It seems the issue is the filter effect. When I take off the (blurry edge) filter, the image goes back to an ellipse shape but when the filter is applied then it looks like a blurry rectangle as shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be an interaction bug between the mask and the filter in Chrome. You can avoid this by doing the mask inside the filter using feComposite and reversing the order of mask and image: pull in the image to the filter using feImage, and use the SourceGraphic to define the mask.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400px" height="350px" >
  <defs>
    <filter id="myfilter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="350">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="20" result="reverse-mask"/>
      <feImage x="0" y="0" width="400"
 height="350"  preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Wilsons_Promontory_National_Park_%28AU%29%2C_Big_Drift_--_2019_--_1683.jpg/1280px-Wilsons_Promontory_National_Park_%28AU%29%2C_Big_Drift_--_2019_--_1683.jpg"/>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="reverse-mask"/>
    </filter>
      </defs>
  
      <g filter="url(#myfilter)">
      <ellipse cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="35%" ry="35%" fill="white" />
      </g>

 </svg>
```

(p.s. it's a good idea to  post complete self-contained working code with an image URL that works - e.g. if the CSS classes are not relevant - remove them.)

Comment: Wow this really helped thank you so much!